# How to get the hash of the avatar via XMPP for offline buddies?

Tags: facebook, hash, xmpp, photo, offline

We need to get the hash of the avatar of a buddy who doesn't appear in online status when we are logged in but I don't get any presence message with the hash of the buddy's avatar who doesn't appear online.
Of course, we can't ask vcard-temp for all the buddies every time by performance reasons.

Is there any ways to get the hash of the avatar for buddies who doesn't appear online when a user logged in via pure XMPP?

Answer (score 0):

Cache it from the last time you saw them online?  Without changing all of the sending clients to put the avatar hash in PEP like it should be, the answer is "no".

Comment: do u know how to set avatar via xmpp in iOS